# pthread_cleanup_pop with argument 0

Tags: pthreads

As per the man page of pthread_cleanup_pop, the cleanup handler will get called if argument of this function is non-zero, else from the cleanup handler installed by the matching pthread_cleanup_push will just get removed.

I am using Ubuntu 3.2.0-32-generic-pae.
But I am seeing that though the parameter is 0, the cleanup handler is getting called.

The thread routine:

```
void *func_a (void *arg)
{      
    pthread_t thr_e;
    void *status;

    pthread_t tid = pthread_self();
    printf("[%2d] D: In thread D [%s]\n", my_time(), (char *)thread_name(tid));

    pthread_cleanup_push(cleanup, NULL);
    pthread_setcanceltype(PTHREAD_CANCEL_DEFERRED, NULL);
    pthread_setcancelstate(PTHREAD_CANCEL_ENABLE, NULL);

    //sleep(1);
    pthread_create(&thr_e, &attr, func_e, NULL);
    printf("[%2d] D: Created thread E [%s]\n", my_time(), (char *)thread_name(thr_e));
    sleep(20);
    printf("[%2d] D: Thread exiting...\n", my_time());
    pthread_cleanup_pop(0);
    return (void *)55;
}
```

Cleanup routine:

```
void
cleanup (void *arg)
{
    printf("[%2d] Calling cleanup...\n", my_time());
}
```

Main thread routine:

```
int main()
{
    ......
    printf("[%2d] Main: Created thread C [%s]\n", my_time(),
               (char *)thread_name(thr_c));
    //sleep(20);
    printf("[%2d] Main: Cancelling Thread D\n", my_time());
    error1 = pthread_cancel(thr_d);
    //sleep(1);
    printf("[%2d] Main: Calcel status %d, %s, %d\n",
               my_time(), error1, (char *)strerror(errno), (int)thr_d);
    printf("[%2d] Main; Exiting...\n", my_time());
}
```

Output is as below:

```
    [ 0] Main: Calcel status 0, Success, -1218630848
    [ 0] Main; Exiting...
    [ 0] Calling cleanup...
```

So here why cleanup() is getting called?
Please let me know what is happening here.

Answer (score 0):

Since "D: Thread exiting" is not printed, one can assume that the main thread cancels D between the push and the pop (during sleep in the example code). This causes the cleanup, which hasn't yet been popped, to execute.

As per [man page](http://www.kernel.org/doc/man-pages/online/pages/man3/pthread_cleanup_push.3.html) (emphasis added):

1. When a thread is canceled, all of the stacked clean-up handlers are popped **and executed** in the reverse of the order in which they were pushed onto the stack.

Comment: The issue happens when D is not sleeping also. I think this point is applicable only when arg is non-zero. Otherwise what is the significance of zero and non-zero args?

Comment: The significance is that, in case the thread was *not* canceled between push and pop, you get to choose whether or not to run the cleanup code.